# Module 'firebase_auth' not found

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, dart

When I attempt to build my project in Xcode I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u15bQ.png) problem.

I just created a new project and when I add packages by 'pub' I get the same issue. I have tried reinstalling flutter main file and nothing changed.

Comment: run these commands in terminal:
cd ios &&
pod install

Comment: I do it before and nothing change